# Django model field dependent on instance

Tags: python, database, django

I am trying to create a model field that is dependent on an instance (specifically an instance of a foreign key).

Example:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user.name)
```

As you can see, I want the file "upload_to" parameter to be dependent on the user. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`upload_to` may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename.

This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system.

```
def _upload_to(instance, filename):
    return str(instance.user.name)

class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_to)
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Unfortunately I'm not all that familiar with Python's object-oriented design patterns. To me this looks like an internal method, so how would I invoke it?

Comment: Jon, this is Django feature, not pure python. This method gets called by django framework if it's what you mean